# Dynamic ng-controller directives based on $routeProvider params

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm working on an app where I want to reuse a single view template multiple times with slight variation on different pages/routes.

For example if I have categories like "toys" and "women's clothing", each page would have the same layout but would have different filter options etc.

I think the best way of doing that would be to use dynamic ng-controller directives in the template.

What I can't figure out is how to pass the category from the route provider to the view to make ng-controller dynamic ...

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/products/:category', {
        templateUrl: '/views/products.html',
        controller: 'productsController'
        // pass :category param to productsController
    });
}]);

app.controller('productsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // get the parameter
    // do something to set the proper filter section from the parameter:
    // i.e women's clothing would contain filter by size, material, type, etc, toys would not
}]);
```

Or am I approaching this all wrong? I don't want to re-code each view since they will be very similar with minor changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `$routeParams` if you are using default ngRouter and `$stateParams` if you are using ui-router. Category will be available in the injected object

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed it wasn't `ui-router`

Comment: oh wow I didn't realize I could just inject it into the controller and get the value from there, I thought it had to be in resolve. Sweet thank you :) I will look at the documentation more.